# pip install fails with heatmap

Tags: python, pip, heatmap

I'm trying to install heatmap with pip but this error comes out and I don't know how to solve it.

This is the error that cmd shows to me.

```
$ pip3 install heatmap
Collecting heatmap
  Using cached heatmap-2.2.1.zip (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\giada\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aq8mcl9q\heatmap_ea8ca237b3b44b6c99b25c44bf100681\setup.py", line 15
          print "On Windows, skipping build_ext."
                ^
      SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("On Windows, skipping build_ext.")?
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Version:

pip: `pip 22.0.4`

python: `Python 3.9.7`

Answer (score 1):

That's a syntax error indicative of Python 2 syntax in Python 3.

The [heatmap project](https://pypi.org/project/heatmap/) is compatible with Python 2 only, quoth [their website](http://jjguy.com/heatmap/):

> Requires Python 2.5+.

That latest version is from 2013, anyway. You'll need to find a more modern, or at least maintained, version to work with Python 3.